# Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-inverse

I have an $n\times p$ matrix $Z$ with $p>n$

I have $A$, a diagonal matrix with positive entries

I would like to know if there is a known relation (as a function of $A$) between

the Moore-Penrose inverse of  $Z^T Z$

and  the Moore-Penrose inverse of  $A Z^T Z A$

what i am looking for is the following: suppose I know the Moore-Penrose of $Z^T Z$ and I know $A$. Can I get, as a function of those two things, the Moore-Penrose inverse of $A Z^T Z A$?

Comment: could you clarify your question

Comment: Please read the FAQ! This is not really at the level suited for MO. You might have more luck at: http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: For the people who think this is trivial: http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/1006007

Comment: Ok, it seems I was a bit hasty in dismissing this question. It is not as trivial as I thought!

Answer (score 2):

"what i am looking for is what is suppose I know the MP of Z^T Z, how can i get the MP of A Z^T Z A using A and the MP of Z^T Z? thanks"

$(A Z^T Z A)^\dagger = (A ((Z^TZ)^\dagger)^\dagger A)^\dagger$

Answer (score 0):

If by 'knwon relation' you mean whether you can convert between these matrices unambiguously then the answer is yes.  The Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse always exists and is unique, and A is nonsingular.  That is all you need.

Comment: what i am looking for is what is suppose I know the MP of Z^T Z, how
can i get the MP of A Z^T Z A using A and the MP of Z^T Z?

thanks